# Brother Printer DCP-J140W is not getting installed on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I am new to Ubuntu & have installed 13.10 amd64 version.
Please explain me easiest way to install driver for my printer DCP-J140W step by step.
Thanks

Comment: Check out this question. I think the solution will work for you, but note that you need to download the correct driver! Also download the DEB packages, not the RPM.